# How do I get fadeTo to work for navbar links?

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, opacity, navbar, fadeto

I am relatively new to HTML/CSS/jQuery, so please forgive the simplicity of my question.

I am trying to create a navbar for a site I'm making. However, I ran into an irritating roadblock: the jQuery isn't doing what I think it should. I'm trying to get it so that when I mouse over a link, the text for the link goes from 0.75 opacity to 1.0 opacity. I tried using the .fadeTo() tag, but when I mouse over the link, nothing happens; it just stays at 0.75 opacity. What is a good way to make my jQuery code do what I want? Here's my HTML, CSS, and jQuery code I currently have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="home_stylesheet.css" />
<link type="text/javascript" href="home_animation.js" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
    <div id="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Research Topics</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Publications</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Graduate Students</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Visiting Scholars</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>



body {
background-image:url('assets/starry_night.jpg');
color:#000;
font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-size:18px;
}

#container, #container div {
background-color:#FFF;
width:700px;
height:1000px;
margin:5px auto;
opacity:0.85;
}

/**********Navbar Styling**********/

#navbar ul {
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

#navbar li {
display:inline;
}

#navbar a {
text-decoration:none;
padding:6px;
color:#000;
text-align:center;
opacity:0.75;
};



$(document).ready(function() {
$("#navbar a").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).fadeTo("fast",1);
});
});
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: why you dont use css :hover?

Answer (score 0):

`.hover()` and `.animate()` are what you are after:

```
$("#navbar a").hover(
    function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({"opacity":1},500);
    }, 
    function() { 
       $(this).stop().animate({"opacity":0.75}, 500);
    }
);
```

You can also use CSS transitions for a similar effect:

```
#navbar a { transition:all 0.5s; }
#navbar a:hover { opacity: 1; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Mu5p9/1/

Comment: The jQuery one didn't work, but the CSS one did! Thanks for the help.